# You apparently created more than one SPF record on your DNS

Tags: email, smtp, spf, dns-zone

I am getting this error from [mail tester](https://www.mail-tester.com)

```
What we retained as your current SPF record is:

v=spf1 include:sparkpostmail.com ~all
More information about this error:

You apparently created more than one SPF record on your DNS. Please make sure to keep only one.
```

Here is what I have:

[image]

The sparkpost line is to use an authenticated smtp server (bulk email). The OVH is to use the webmail.

Currently this works fine in hotmail, gmail, but protonmail give me an [alert](https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/email-has-failed-its-domains-authentication-requirements-warning/) related with this issue. Should I merge both lines? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

The correct SPF record for these services would be:

```
"v=spf1 include:sparkpostmail.com include:mx.ovh.com ~all"
```

When you are sure this works as intended you should then change the `~all` soft fail to the hard fail `-all`.

Comment: The order of what comes first is important?  I mean ovh/sparkpost

Comment: Afaik the order is irrelevant